# Android : connect two devices by bluetooth and enable internet access programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect two Android devices (already paired) by Bluetooth and enable automatically access to Internet in one of them.

This is possible by accessing in settings and enabling the below check case :

[image]

Do you have any idea how can i do this programmatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using `WifiManager`'s `setWifiApEnabled()` method.

However, this method is only available up to Android SDK 27. It is marked as a SystemAPI and requires `android.Manifest.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED`.

It is therefore strongly unrecommended to implement this functionality for the reason that Google doesn’t provide any official API call for enabling the mobile hotspot.

You can read more about this topic here:

https://medium.com/@jean.creuzedeschatelliers/how-to-activate-the-mobile-hotspot-on-android-programmatically-or-not-5931e44097e3

Comment: Hi, yes you're right, unfortunately i got an issue when i try to use this function in Android O.
Thanks for your answer (y).

Comment: It's normal, as this function is deprecated and marked "This API is nolonger supported " in Android SDK 27 (Android O). Please accept my answer if it helped